# ArrayAdapter add only one item on listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I have a simple listview that should display a complete name of a person. There are three fields, "name", "middlename" and "lastname" to each item of the listview. The problem is, I only populate one item. The last one on the code; This is the output I get: [image]

Notice that I have text only on the "lastname" field, and that's the problem. This is where I call the ArrayAdapter on my java class:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> n = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.teste, R.id.name, name);
        this.setListAdapter(n);
        ArrayAdapter<String> mn = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.teste, R.id.middlename, middlename);
        this.setListAdapter(mn);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ln = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.teste, R.id.lastname, lastname);
        this.setListAdapter(ln);
```

this are my strings:

```
    String [] name = {"Carol", "Heloisa", "Thaiane", "Hannah"};
    String [] middlename = {"Martins", "Bechelli", "Soldani", "Lopes"};
    String [] lastname = {"Santos", "Pereira", "Borges", "Machado"};
```

and this is teste.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Name: "
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="MiddleName"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/middlename"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="LastName"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/lastname"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Why can't I get the 3 TextViews populated? Thanks.

Comment: you need to create custom Adapter by extending `ArrayAdapter `

Comment: You are overwriting your setted list adapter 2 times. Lastname overwrites middleman overwrites name. I suggest using a custom adapter or extending ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Yes it will only show the last name as you can only set one adapter. Therefore you will have to make a custom adapter!

Comment: Hmmm, how do I do that? @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges: See following [Custom ArrayAdapter for a ListView (Android)](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)

Comment: To all of you that have answered, I have tried it before, but I always got a NullPointerException and I couldn't figure out how to solve it. So I came with this code I'm showing you guys. But thanks, what I really wanted to know is if it was possible to do what I'm trying the way I'm trying... I'll figure something out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should not call 3 times `setAdapter`,because last Adapter will override pre one,that's why only last textview show items.

Considering your case,I think you should use `SimpleAdapter` or custom `BaseAdapter` to make it.You can refer [ListView With BaseAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224855/listview-with-baseadapter),or google **android BaseAdapter**

Comment: I have tried it before, but I always got a NullPointerException and I couldn't figure out how to solve it. So I came with this code I'm showing you guys. But thanks, what I really wanted to know is if it was possible to do what I'm trying the way I'm trying... I'll figure something out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For a listview we can able to set only one adapter.

My Suggestion is use custom adapter instead of arrayadapter.

For adapter use below code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
    String [] name;
    String [] middlename;
    String [] lastname;
    Context context;
 int [] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] name,String[] middlename,String[] lastname) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context=mainActivity;
        this.context=context;
        this.name=name;
        this.middlename=middlename;
        this.lastname=lastname;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView nametv,middlenametv,lastnametv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;       
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
             holder.nametv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.middlenametv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             holder.lastnametv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

         holder.nametv.setText(name[position]);
         holder.middlenametv.setText(middlename[position]);
         holder.lastnametv.setText(lastname[position]);

        });   
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

And set adapter in the activity like below

```
lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, name,middlename,lastname));
```

Comment: That's good, thanks. I'll try that tomorrow, and give you the feed back!